# count how many of an object type there are in a list Python

Tags: python, list, object-type

If I have a list in python:

```
a = [1, 1.23, 'abc', 'ABC', 6.45, 2, 3, 4, 4.98]
```

Is there a very easy way to count the amount of an object type there are in `a`?
Something simpler than the following but produces the same result:

```
l = [i for i in a if type(a[i]) == int]
print(len(l))
```

Hopefully I made myself clear.

Comment: The above produces `TypeError` FYI. I think you meant l = [i for i in a if type(i) == int]

Comment: The `TypeError` is because `i` is a value from the list, not an index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = [1, 1.23, 'abc', 'ABC', 6.45, 2, 3, 4, 4.98]

sum(isinstance(i, int) for i in a)
```

which returns

```
4
```

Answer (score 13):

Use `isinstance` to do your type checks, and then `sum` the Boolean values to get the count (`True` is 1, `False` is 0):

```
sum(isinstance(x, int) for x in a)
```

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to do it.

Here's one that takes advantage of the list fast [*map()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) function and the C-speed [*list.count()*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange) method using them both as they were intended:

```
>>> a = [1, 1.23, 'abc', 'ABC', 6.45, 2, 3, 4, 4.98]
>>> map(type, a).count(int)
4
```

In Python 3, *map()* returns an iterator so you need a small modification, `list(map(type, a)).count(int)`.

The other approaches using *sum()* and *Counter()* as also reasonable (readable and used as intended) but are a bit slower.

Comment: using `type()` is more specific and therefore preferred, in most circumstances, over `isinstance(variable, int)` especially if you don't want `class bool` (i.e. True False) to return `True` as a class of `integer`.  While `bool` inherits from `int`, they are different types (i.e. classes).

Comment: @Bilal See the note, "In Python 3, map() returns an iterator so you need a small modification, list(map(type, a)).count(int)."

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Counter` !

```
from collections import Counter

type_counts = Counter(type(x) for x in a)

assert type_counts[int] == 4
assert type_counts[float] == 3
assert type_counts[str] == 2
```

This won't help you if you want to count all types *and subtypes* of a particular type though. For instance, the `basestring` type does not appear in the results and I can't use the above code to count it.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
>>> a = [1, 1.23, 'abc', 'ABC', 6.45, 2, 3, 4, 4.98]
>>> len(filter(lambda e: isinstance(e, int), a))
4
```

You should know that any approach that uses `isinstance` will count `True` or `False` as an int since bool is a subclass of int:

```
>>> isinstance(False, int)
True
>>> type(False)==int
False
```

So if the distinction between `int` and `bool` matters, use `type(whatever)==int` instead.